# ObjectiveFlickr - how to call getSizes on a photo ID not known until the response?

Tags: ios, flickr

I'm building a free music instrument iPhone app with the Flickr API and ObjectiveFlickr. A random photo from the interestingness list is displayed in the background, but I can't center it without knowing its size. (So I can reset the `UIWebView` frame)

I've been researching this for awhile, and it's my first time playing with a web service API. =)

Since I don't know the photo ID until after I receive the response from the interestingness feed, how would I call `flickr.photo.getSizes` on the response? This is what I have so far:

```
- (void)flickrAPIRequest:(OFFlickrAPIRequest *)inRequest didCompleteWithResponse:(NSDictionary *)inResponseDictionary{
 int randomResponse = arc4random() % 49;
 photoDict = [[inResponseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"photos.photo"] objectAtIndex:randomResponse];
 
 NSString *photoID = [photoDict valueForKeyPath:@"id"];
 
 NSLog(@"%@",photoID);
 
 NSURL *photoURL = [flickrContext photoSourceURLFromDictionary:photoDict size:OFFlickrMediumSize];
 NSString *htmlSource = [NSString stringWithFormat:
       @"<html>"
       @"<head>"
       @"  <style>body { margin: 0; padding: 0; } </style>"
       @"</head>"
       @"<body>"
       @"<img src=\"%@\" />"
       @"</body>"
       @"</html>"
       , photoURL];
 
 [webView loadHTMLString:htmlSource baseURL:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the behavior I wanted by loading the returned image into a UIImageView. Here's the code, hope it helps someone:

```
- (void)flickrAPIRequest:(OFFlickrAPIRequest *)inRequest didCompleteWithResponse:(NSDictionary *)inResponseDictionary{
    int randomResponse = arc4random() % 49;
    photoDict = [[inResponseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"photos.photo"] objectAtIndex:randomResponse];

    NSString *photoID = [photoDict valueForKeyPath:@"id"];

    NSLog(@"%@",photoID);

    NSURL *photoURL = [flickrContext photoSourceURLFromDictionary:photoDict size:OFFlickrMediumSize];

    NSData *receivedData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                             photoURL] retain];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData] ;
    NSLog(@"%i",image.size);

    randomImage.image = image;

    //[webView loadHTMLString:htmlSource baseURL:nil];
}
```